# reset password label text change

Tags: wp-login-form, reset, labels

[image]

Please see my screenshot. I want to change the "New Password" label text and "login" text.  I used following code to change the hint text.

```
function change_password_hint ( $text ) {
    if(basename($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"])=='wp-login.php' && $text == 'Hint: The password should be at least twelve characters long. To make it stronger, use upper and lower case letters, numbers, and symbols like ! " ? $ % ^ &amp; ).'){
        $text = 'Use upper and lower case letters, numbers, and symbols like ! " ? $ % ^ &amp; ).';
    }


    return $text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'change_password_hint' );
```

How can i change the label and footer text??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we want to have the *reset password* form to look like this:

[image: reset]

then we could use the following hooks:

```
/**
 * Modify the password hint
 */
add_filter( 'password_hint', function( $hint )
{
  return __( 'Use upper and lower case letters, numbers, and symbols like ! " ? $ % ^ &amp; ).' );
} );

/**
 * Modify 'New password' text
 */
add_action( 'validate_password_reset', function( $errors )
{
    add_filter( 'gettext', 'wpse_gettext', 10, 2 ); 
    return $message;
});


/**
 * Modify 'Log in' text
 */
add_action( 'resetpass_form', function()
{
    add_filter( 'gettext', 'wpse_gettext', 10, 2 ); 
});
```

The `wpse_gettext` helper function is defined as:

```
function wpse_gettext( $translated_text, $text )
{
    // Modify gettext if there's a match
    switch ( $text )
    {
        case 'New password' :           
            remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );
            $translated_text = __( 'Use this password, or type a new one over it' );
            break;
        case 'Log in' :
            remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );
            $translated_text = __( 'Already registered before? Click here to log-in' );
            $match = true;          
        default:
    }  
    return $translated_text;
}
```

where we remove the filter callback as soon as it has been used once.

We also try to hook into nearby hooks to minimize the number of `gettext` checks.

Also note the danger of using `gettext` functions within the `gettext` filter ;-)

That's why I moved the `remove_filter` above the `__()` calls, to avoid infinite loops.